# How to validate an uploaded CSV file if rows are present or not in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a CSV file which should be validated on uploading in the form. 'Error' should pop up if any rows are missing in the column else it should show 'validated'. I am new to java script and have tried below code but even though rows are not empty the code is showing 'error'. can somebody help me out in identifying where i am going wrong?

The CSV file is as follows:

```
serial.no.   name
   1         abc
   2         def
```

if any row is missing it should show 'error' else 'validated'

This is my javascript code:

```
<script>
    function checkfilesize()
    {
        if (document.getElementById("myFile").files[0].size > 100000) // about 8 kb here,20971522 mb for bytes.
        {
            alert("File size must under 10kb!");
        document.getElementById("myFile").value="";
        return;
        }
    }


function newDoc()
    {
        var flag = 0;
        var fileUpload = document.getElementById("myFile");
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) 
        {
            var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
            for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) 
            {
                var cells = rows[i].split(",");
                for (var j = 0; j <cells.length; j++) 
                {
                    if(cells[j]=="")
                    {
                    window.alert("ERROR");
                    flag=1;
                    break; 
                }

            }   
            if(flag==1)
            break;          
            }
            if (flag)
            window.alert("ERROR");
            else
            window.alert("VALIDATED");                                  
        }
        reader.readAsText(fileUpload.files[0]);
    }       


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproduce your code, it worked well if your csv file correct format.
With error case, you need add check for return character `cells[j] == "\r"` in case empty line in csv file.

If dont check `cells[j] == "\r"` your code still show VALID while having empty line in csv file.

```
if (cells[j] == "" || cells[j] == "\r") {
      window.alert("ERROR");
      flag = 1;
      break;
}
```

Ensure that your csv file content correct as

```
serial.no.,name
1,abc
2,def
```

This content is incorrect (have comma after second item)

```
serial.no.,name
1,abc,
2,def
```

```js
 function checkfilesize() {
        if (document.getElementById("myFile").files[0].size > 100000) // about 8 kb here,20971522 mb for bytes.
        {
            alert("File size must under 10kb!");
            document.getElementById("myFile").value = "";
            return;
        }
    }

    function newDoc() {
        var flag = 0;
        var fileUpload = document.getElementById("myFile");
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
            for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var cells = rows[i].split(",");
                if(cells.length < 2){
                   flag = 1;
                   break;
                }
                for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                    if (cells[j] == "" || cells[j] == "\r") {
                        window.alert("ERROR");
                        flag = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (flag == 1)
                    break;
            }
            if (flag)
                window.alert("ERROR");
            else
                window.alert("VALIDATED");
        }
        reader.readAsText(fileUpload.files[0]);
    }
```

```html
<input type="file" id="myFile" />
<button onclick="checkfilesize();">Check Size</button>
<button onclick="newDoc();">Check Format</button>
```

Comment: Hi Hien, thanks for the help. But, i wanted to validate if cell data in a row is missing or not.if any one cell is missed it should show error else it should show validated. I have tried cells[j]== null, cells[j]==undefined and if(!cells[j]), but none of them worked. Could you please let me know on how to do it. @Hien

Comment: I tried in my local, it still show valid with your data file. Can you open with notepad and past content here?

Comment: I updated answer check cells.length < 2 flag = 1 and break for loop